# Connect to SQL Server Express edition from node.js driver mssql (Tedious wrapper)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, tedious

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL:
> mssql://testuser:testuser@192.168.1.70\SQLEXPRESS/MyTestDB

The node package is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

As per their `Quick Example`

```
await sql.connect('mssql://username:password@localhost/database')
```

I am doing this

```
await sql.connect('mssql://testuser:testuser@192.168.1.70\\SQLEXPRESS/MyTestDB');
```

My details are:

- SQL Server instance: `192.168.1.70\SQLEXPRESS`
- DB name: MyTestDB
- uid/pwd: testuser, testuser

I have no issues connecting from SQL Server Management Studio from a remote machine, so what is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json object works, not plain string !

```
    let config = {
        user: 'testuser',
        password: 'testuser',
        server: '192.168.1.70\\SQLEXPRESS',  
        database: 'MyTestDB'
    }
```

**Update:**
From a github issue it became clearer the Quick Example format is a Uri, not a connection string.

So instead of:

```
'mssql://testuser:testuser@192.168.1.70\\SQLEXPRESS/MyTestDB'
```

I should use the below, which I've since confirmed also works!

```
'mssql://testuser:testuser@192.168.1.70/SQLEXPRESS/MyTestDB'
```